# C++ if constexpr vs template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, specialization, if-constexpr

Consider these 2 examples

**Example 1**

```
template<Type type>
static BaseSomething* createSomething();

template<>
BaseSomething* createSomething<Type::Something1>()
{
     return Something1Creator.create();
}

template<>
BaseSomething* createSomething<Type::Something2>()
{
     return Something2Creator.create();
}

.... // other somethings
```

**Example2**

```
template<Type type>
static BaseSomething* createSomething() 
{
    if constexpr(type == Type::Something1)
    {
        return Something1Creator.create();
    }
    else if constexpr(type == Type::Something2)
    {
        return Something2Creator.create();
    }
    // Other somethings
}
```

I know that these two examples are *conceptually* the same, but consider these functional is in a `SomethingFactory.hpp` file, and my `main.cpp` includes it.

In `main.cpp` I may create only  type `Something1` without ever knowing that other `Something` types exist.

I really **do care about size of my executable** in the end. What do you think which pattern shall I take for my executable to be at minimal size? Or there is no big deal about these, and we are all doomed anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you think which pattern shall I take for my executable to be at minimal size?

In both cases, if you only instantiate `createSomething<Type::Something1>` you will get one function definition that is effectively one line of code.

> I really **do care about size of my executable in the end**

Then get rid of the `static`.  Template functions are implicitly inline, but `static` functions will have unique copies for each translation unit.

> I know that these two examples are conceptually the same

They are not.

`createSomething<void>` is a defined function using **Example2**, and is undefined using **Example 1**.

Comment: I did not get this line *createSomething<void> is a defined function using Example2, and is undefined using Example 1.* why is `createSomething<void> is defined in Example2 and not in Example 1?

Comment: @TheScore are you familiar with what a "function definition" is?  You can point to the location of the definition of `createSomething<void>` in **Example2**, but you can not point to it in **Example 1**, because it is not there.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Your comment lead to a post saying *A template is a “pattern” that the compiler uses to generate a family of classes or functions. In order for the compiler to generate the code, it must see both the template definition (not just declaration) and the specific types/whatever used to “fill in” the template.* Since in  Example2 template func with definition it stamps out implement for different types. Did i get it correctly?

Comment: @TheScore I believe so.

Comment: The not-specialized declaration of template<Type type>
static BaseSomething* createSomething(); is not defined in example 1 so createSomething<void> is not defined, but it is legal to let a declaration without definition like this ?